# AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'dump'

Tags: python

I just installed pyyaml, with pip intsall pyaml.
This is my code right now

```
import yaml
filepath = input("input path to file: ")
data = {}  # start a new dictionary

with open(filepath) as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):  # iterate by-line
        if index % 4 == 0:
            host = line  # do any needed validation here
            data[host] = {}  # start another dict to write to
        elif index % 4 == 1:
            data[host]["hostname"] = line  # host is still the block header!

with open("destination.yml", "w") as fh:
    yaml.dump(data, fh)
```

It always errors out with AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'dump'
according to the documentation that should work fine.

Comment: Do you have a file named `yaml.py` or a directory named `yaml` at the same level as the script?

Comment: @jakub yes I do. Is that what's breaking it? I will test and report back.Edit: seems to have worked partially. For whatever reason the code only prints the top server and doesn't do all of them

Comment: Yes, `import yaml` will prefer the local `yaml.py` over pyyaml. You should rename that file to something else.